# How do I produce a basis of cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, arithmetic-geometry, cohomology, etale-cohomology

Suppose I am discussing a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field with my friend on the phone and I want to make a statement about its $l$-adic cohomology (integral or rational). Then how could I choose a basis for it so that it would be describable on the phone?

I could choose several subvarieties (which can be described via their equations) and take their images in the cohomology. However that generally won't be enough to produce a basis. For example I could be describing the cohomology in odd degree (or there could be Hodge numbers off the diagonal in even degree).

For $H^1$ one could take some elements of $\pi_1$ (which are pretty describable being finite covers of a projective variety) and take their images in the abelianization. By Poincaré duality this covers one more degree but what about the rest?

If the field in question has characteristic $0$ then rational homotopy theory might solve the problem but I am not clear on the details.

I guess this question can be posed in other settings as well (e.g. singular cohomology of compact manifolds) but in algebraic geometry you often can reduce everything to finitely many bits of information so I feel the chance of success is higher.

Comment: For mod $\ell^n$ cohomology I think you can cover your variety by $K(\pi,1)$s and then do group cohomology cocycles. For $\ell$-adic cohomology a basis is sort of an infinite amount of information. If you have a field embedding into the complex numbers you can use a basis for the singular homology but such an embedding is also an infinite amount of information.

Comment: If you want an effective way to compute étale cohomology, there is this paper of Madore and Orgogozo: https://msp.org/ant/2015/9-7/ant-v9-n7-p04-s.pdf

Comment: I don't think you can hope for a good answer that works in all cases, but it is certainly common that you can find a basis consisting of monomials in Chern classes of easily described vector bundles.

Comment: To rephrase what Will said: you can't. Even in the simplest example, $H^{2n}(X^n)=\mathbb Q_\ell(n)$. A basis is any nonzero element. You can't choose one without the axiom of choice. And you shouldn't because that destroys information. You say that you're over an algebraically closed field, but, really, it's over the field of definition and by passing to the algebraic cover you've destroyed the information of the Galois action, part of which is warning you that you can't actually choose elements. And that's why people come up with names like $\mathbb Q_\ell(n)$ rather than bases.

Comment: @BenWieland there is a map $CH^{2n}(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}_l\to H^{2n}(X, \mathbb{Q}_l)$. I can take the image of $[X]$ under this map, right?

Comment: No, there is no such map, not without choosing infinitely many roots of unity. The natural map lands in $H^{2n}(X;\mathbb Q_\ell(n))$. (I messed up the twist in my previous comment. The correct statement is that for $X$ smooth, complete, and geometrically connected, $H^{2n}(X;\mathbb Q_\ell)=\mathbb Q_\ell(-n)$, or, equivalently, $H^{2n}(X;\mathbb Q_\ell(n))=\mathbb Q_l$. Dropping the hypotheses to nonempty $n$-dimensional (equidimensional) variety, there is surjective $H_c^{2n}(X;\mathbb Q_\ell(n))\to\mathbb Q_\ell$.)

Comment: @BenWieland but I am ignoring the galois representation, the underlying vector spaces are the same for all twists, aren't they? Isn't there a map from the chow ring of a smooth complex projective variety to the $l$-adic cohomology in even degrees?

Comment: Sure, changing the twist doesn't change the dimension of the cohomology. But just because two vector spaces have the same dimension, doesn't mean that "the underlying vector spaces are the same." They are isomorphic, but not the same. You can't ignore the Galois action if you want to communicate a specific basis over the phone. And if you do make unnatural choices, you shouldn't say "there is a map." When people talk about the cycle class map, they mean **the** cycle class map that everyone agrees about.

Comment: @BenWieland but there is a canonical isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}_l$-singular cohomology and $l$-adic cohomology and a canonical map from the rational Chow ring to the rational singular cohomology.

Comment: @crispr You are right, we can trivilize the Tate twist in singular cohomology using a generator of the first homology of the circle and use this to trivialize étale cohomology. Using the projective line over $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ and specialization isomorphisms, we can trivialize Tate twists over any algebraically closed field. Now, to find a basis of cohomology, you may play look for a generating family for integral $\ell$-adic cohomology. By Nakayama, you are reduced to find a basis for $\mathbb{F}_\ell$-linear étale cohomology. The reference I gave above is then relevant.

Comment: If you know there no torsion in integral $\ell$-adic cohomology, the method I suggest actually provide a basis. Otherwise it still gives a generating family.

Comment: No, there is no such natural isomorphism. Check your sources. Even for singular cohomology there is an action of the Galois group of $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb R$. There is no canonical fundamental class $[\mathbb P^1]\in H_2(\mathbb P^2;\mathbb Z)$. To choose a fundamental class is to choose an orientation, but the Galois group reverses orientation of odd dimensional varieties. But for even dimensional varieties, $\mathbb Z(2)=\mathbb Z$. Still, the Galois group of the field of definition acts on the Chow group.

Comment: @BenWieland All these discussions about cycle classes are irrelevant when it comes to find a basis. The question is about finding a basis of cohomology. Since they are cohomology classes which are not invariant under the Galois action, such a basis will involve non-algebraic classes. In particular, I never said I would consider a basis made of cycles classes only because such a basis does not exist for a general algebraic variety. And the choice of an orientation of the circle does provide a basis of Betti $H^2$ of the complex projective line by very elementary arguments.